# $_FILES return empty in update_post_meta Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to access my custom field file(image) value using $_FILES on on post save but it
return a empty string, I tried using $_POST but it returns only the name of the file i want to get the file name + mime type And I tried using $FILES[input_name][type] it also return's a empty value. I tried many solutions but didn't work

```
//theme shop menu
class BakentakeShopMenu{
    function __construct(){
        //register shop menu custom post type
        add_action( 'init', array($this,'create_menuitem_cpt'), 1, );
        //register custom fields for shop menu post type
        add_action("add_meta_boxes",[$this,'shop_items_custom_fields'],2);
        
        add_action('save_post',[$this,'save_shop_items_fields']);
        add_action("rest_api_init",[$this,"add_menu_data_to_rest"]);
    }

    // add menu items to the rest api 
    function add_menu_data_to_rest(){
        // register_rest_route("wp/v2","menu_data",[
        //  "methods" => "GET",
        //  "callback" => [$this,"set_menu_data_to_rest_config"]
        // ]);
        register_rest_field("menuitem","menuData",array(
            "get_callback" => [$this,'register_menu_item_data_rest_field'],
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema' => null,
            )
        );
    }

    function register_menu_item_data_rest_field($post){
        $itemName = get_post_meta($post['id'],'item_name_value',true);
        $itemDescription = get_post_meta($post['id'],'item_description_value',true);
        $itemPrice = get_post_meta($post['id'],'item_price_value',true);
        $itemDiscountPrice = get_post_meta($post['id'],'item_discount_value',true);
        $itemImage = get_post_meta($post['id'],'item_image_value',true);

        return [$itemName,$itemDescription,$itemPrice,$itemDiscountPrice,$itemImage];
    }

// Register Custom Post Type Menu Item
function create_menuitem_cpt() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Menu Items', 'Post Type General Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Menu Item', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Menu Items', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Menu Item', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
        'archives' => __( 'Menu Item Archives', 'textdomain' ),
        'attributes' => __( 'Menu Item Attributes', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Menu Item:', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Menu Items', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_items' => __( 'View Menu Items', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'textdomain' ),
        'featured_image' => __( 'Featured Image', 'textdomain' ),
        'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list' => __( 'Menu Items list', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Menu Items list navigation', 'textdomain' ),
        'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter Menu Items list', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-cart',
        'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', 'custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'menuitem', $args );
}

    //add custom field settings
    function shop_items_custom_fields(){
        add_meta_box(
            'shop_item',
            'shop items',
            array($this,'shop_items_config'),
            'menuitem',
            'normal',
            'low',
            ''

        );
    }
    // save custom field values 
    function save_shop_items_fields($post_id ){
        //item name
            update_post_meta(
                $post_id ,
                "item_name_value",
                $_POST['item_name']
            );
        //item description
            update_post_meta(
                $post_id ,
                "item_description_value",
                $_POST['item_description']
            );
        //item price
            update_post_meta(
                $post_id ,
                "item_price_value",
                $_POST['item_price']
            );
        //discount price
            update_post_meta(
                $post_id ,
                "item_discount_value",
                $_POST['item_price']
            );
        //Image
            update_post_meta(
                $post_id ,
                "item_image_value",
                $_FILES['item_image']
            );          
    }   
    //custom fields config
    function shop_items_config($post){
        $itemName = get_post_meta($post->ID,'item_name_value',true);
        $itemDescription = get_post_meta($post->ID,'item_description_value',true);
        $itemPrice = get_post_meta($post->ID,'item_price_value',true);
        $itemDiscountPrice = get_post_meta($post->ID,'item_discount_value',true);
        $itemImage = get_post_meta($post->ID,'item_image_value',true);

        //upload images
        $wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $itemImage;
        $file = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png";
        ?>
        <form action = "" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1><?php print_r($itemImage) ?></h1>
            <div class="shop-items-form">
                <div class="shop-items-form-field">
                    <label for="item-name">Item Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $itemName ?>"/>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-items-form-field">
                    <label for="item-description">Item Description</label>
                    <textarea name="item_description"><?php echo $itemDescription ?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-items-form-field__wraper">
                    <div class="shop-items-form-field">
                        <label for="itemPrice">Item Price</label>
                        <input type="number" name="item_price" value="<?php echo $itemPrice ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shop-items-form-field">
                        <label for="discount-price">Discount Price</label>
                        <input type="number" name="discount_price" value="<?php echo $itemDiscountPrice ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-items-form-field">
                    <label for="discount-price">Add Item Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="item_image" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" value=<?php $itemImage ?>/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
};

new BakentakeShopMenu;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your form allows file uploads, it is contained in the default Wordpress Post form so you have to let Wordpress know that the form may contain files. This option its disabled by default in all post forms (Post, page, **custom post type**, etc).

```
<?php
// Add this hook on your init file
    add_action('post_edit_form_tag','update_edit_form'));
// Create the function that allows file uploads on post forms
    function update_edit_form(){
      echo 'enctype="multipart/form-data"';
    }
?>
```